# Can we increase the size of data type?

Tags: c

For Example : Can we increase the size of long long variable to store value of bigger size.(more than 64 bit)

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)?

Comment: No, you cannot increase the size of data type. Its solution is to use structures

Comment: If you need bigger data size, you should change the data type you use instead

Comment: To change the size of a type, you'd have to have a compiler that is built to be configurable to use larger sizes for the type (and you'd probably still have a limited range of options — for example, GCC can often be compiled so that `-m32` gives you a 32-bit `long` and `-m64` gives you a 64-bit `long`), or you'd have to build the compiler to use a larger size all the time.  Changing the size of a type like `long long` is decidedly non-trivial — and would require considerable skill.

Comment: What is your actual problem? Ask about that rather than asking about your solution, which is a non-solution.

Comment: You can't edit native types. If you need to store huge numbers, and if you don't need to support all compilers/platform, you can probably rely on 128bits integers. I know that recent version of GCC support those, probably other compilers.

Comment: Why would you need a primitive type bigger than 64 bits? A 64 bit primitive can support over 18 _quintillion_ different values. Yes, over 18,000,000,000,000,000,000 possibilities. If you are actually writing code to handle numbers that big, you can write your own variable length big num implementation. Or find someone else's you have permission to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about compiler implementation: Yes, I think the C standard doesn't impose any upper bound, only minimums (like char is 8 bits or more)  and limits on relative sizes (like, long can't be shorter than int). So you can set the size to anything in your own compiler (or a backend to an existing compiler), or provide command line switches to select it at compile time.

If you are asking from application programmers perspective: **No**, I don't know of a compiler which would support this. It would have the complication, that you would also need all libraries compiled with custom integer type sizes, because if library code expects a long to be 64 bits, and you call it with 128 bit long, there'll be trouble. At machine code level, there is no C type, there's just raw bytes in registers and memory, and the machine code just has to handle them right everywhere in the application and the librararies.

Perhaps you should ask a question about what you actually want to achieve, there is probably a solution. Use a bigint library? Use a compiler-specific non-standard large integer type? Use a struct or an array with several integers in it (a bigint library basically does this under the hood)? Use floating point? Use ascii text numbers?