# C++ adaptive type deduction

Tags: c++, integer-overflow, type-deduction

Recently, I've been playing around with C++'s type deduction. While doing so I came across something weird. When I run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto n = 40;
    auto factorial = 1;

    for(int i = 1; i <=n; ++i)
    {
        factorial *= i;
    }

    cout << "Factorial of " << n << " = " << factorial <<endl;   
    cout << "Size of factorial: " << sizeof(factorial) << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

It prints this out:

```
Factorial of 40 = 0
Size of factorial: 4
```

So it's obvious that there was a buffer overflow, so `factorial` is `0`. But what I don't understand is why auto didn't *adapt* to something like a `unsigned long long`, and why it stayed as an `int` (4 bytes)? Is there some way to fix this?

Comment: "For variables, specifies that the type of the variable that is being declared will be automatically deduced from its initializer." https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto The type is only deduced from the initializer, not from any future use of the variable.

Comment: @John -- Thanks. Is there some workaround for this?

Comment: `unsigned long long factorial = 1;` should do it. It's up to the programmer to know what kind of data they need to process.

Comment: Yeah, but that is the thing I don't want to do... I need to have the type deducted.

Comment: @Xilpex what about setting you le variable being equal to 1UL ?

Comment: "I need to have the type deduced" why? Sounds like an XY problem. If we had more context about why you need this we might be able to offer a solution.

Comment: @ClémentJean -- That would work, but in a way, you're still giving the type.

Comment: Also I think 40 factorial is 8.1591528e+47 according to my calculator. `ULL` is only guaranteed to handle up to 1.8446744e+19. You need some kind of big integer library.

Comment: @John -- I am writing a compiler that transpiles to C++. In it, I need the type deduced.

Comment: Just so we're clear - fundamental types like this declared as local variables are allocated using automatic storage. That means the compiler allocates a set amount of size for the variable at compile time. That space can't grow as the number gets bigger. If you need the number to grow you need a smart object that knows when it needs to grow and can handle dynamic memory allocation as required.

Comment: @John -- Yes. That would work.

Comment: `auto int n = 40;` ? What kind of compiler are you using that accepts that code?

Comment: @NikosC. -- I am using `clang`

Comment: Then you're using an old version of clang it seems that still accepts the old meaning of `auto` (which means "not static".) Why did you write `auto int` to begin with though?

Comment: @NikosC. -- I am using `clang version 7.0.0`. And about the `auto int`, that was a typo.

Comment: I just tried it and clang 7 issues a warning: "warning: 'auto' storage class specifier is not permitted in C++11, and will not be supported in future releases [-Wauto-storage-class]" In your code, `auto` is the storage class. It's not auto type deduction. But again, what do you think `auto int` would do?

Comment: to be clear, there's no buffer overflow here. It's just the value being overflown

Comment: `auto factorial = 1ULL;` (Your compiler should be doing the type deduction for values in your language, and emitting the proper C++ code. Don't try to pass it off to the C++ compiler to do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, the type is only a compile-time concept. By the time you actually start running the program, it’s forgotten all about what types variable are; it cannot adapt at runtime.

The best you can do is use some sort of [bignum type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) which will automatically grow as needed, but it still stays the same type.

Comment: Long story short, do not use `auto` if you need your variable to be of a specific type.

Answer (score 1):

> So its obvious that there was a buffer overflow

The multiplication result overflows, but there's no buffer overflow here, which is when you write a bigger amount of data into the buffer

> why auto didn't adapt to something like a unsigned long long, and why it stayed as an int (4 bytes)? Is there some way to fix this?

`1` is an int literal, so obviously if you use `auto factorial = 1;` it'll create an int variable and reserve a fixed amount of memory for that variable. The size can't be changed because if you increase it then it'll be flooded into nearby variables

If you want dynamic sizing capability then handle that yourself by allocating memory on the heap, just like how containers like `std::vector` and `std::unordered_map` do. That requires a lot more memory and CPU resources which means they can't apply to basic POD types because those are supposed to be fast and as close to hardware as possible. If you want big integer arithmetic then use an [arbitrary-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) or [Boost.Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html). Or read the [bigint](/questions/tagged/bigint), [biginteger](/questions/tagged/biginteger), [largenumber](/questions/tagged/largenumber), [arbitrary-precision](/questions/tagged/arbitrary-precision) tags for more information

See

- [Why are types always a certain size no matter its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50819413/995714)
- [Can we increase the size of data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34939422/995714)